# conda: package missing after installing offline

Tags: conda

I need to create a conda env with elasticsearch on a machine with no internet. I scp'd elasticsearch-5.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 to the machine and ran the following:

```
conda install elasticsearch-5.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2

[      COMPLETE      ]|#########################################################################################################| 100%
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#########################################################################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#########################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#########################################################################################################| 100%

$ conda list | grep elasticsearch
elasticsearch             5.3.0                    py36_0    <unknown>
```

Then, I tried to create the env as follows:

```
conda create -n my_env --offline --copy -y -q  elasticsearch
```

However, this fails with:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata:
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - elasticsearch

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda elasticsearch
```

What do I need to do to create this env?

Answer (score 0):

when you create an env, this env is going to adopte the default packages, so elasticsearch won't be in.

what you should do:

```
conda create -n my_env --offline
```

and then

```
conda install -n my_env /path_to/elasticsearch-5.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

and to verify:

```
#source activate my_env

(my_env)#conda list elasticsearch
```